# Bootstrap-table How to make height adjust to show data

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table to create my table, and it functions perfectly, but it looks a bit strange because the height seems to just be fixed, regardless of how much data is in it. So if I only have 6 records, there is just this awkward empty space underneath. Here is my html:

```
<table class="table" data-toggle="table" data-page-size="10" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true">Username</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">Full Name</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">Points</th>
        {% for subject in subjects %}
        <th data-sortable="true">{{ subject }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'profile' username=user.username %}">{{ user.username }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</td>
        {% for item in user.profile.points %}
        <td>{{ item.1 }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

And here is a screenshot of my page:
[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "height" property.

```
 $table.bootstrapTable({
        ***height: getHeight(),***
        columns: [
            [

function getHeight() {
    return $(window).height() - $('h1').outerHeight(true);
}
```

[See this example.](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/welcome.html)